# Best Practice to ensure copy of a DataFrame (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy

I have a pandas DataFrame, `projthemes_df` which contains three columns.

[image]

I want to subset it into a 2-column DataFrame. I've been using code like this because this is representative of the examples I see most often:

```
theme_by_code_df = projthemes_df[['code', 'name']]
```

This works.

[image]

There is duplication in the resulting DF.

When I tried

```
theme_by_code_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

I got an error:

[image]

Apparently, the error is based on [Returning a view versus a copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) (although the link in the error message is incorrect).

The question:

I've been using

```
df2 = df1[['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

thinking I was getting a new DF in df2. OOps!

[image]

So, what's the best practice to ensure that I'm working with a DF I can safely modify?

I thought it would work to initialize an empty dataframe before doing the selection, but I got the same error with this code.

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame()
tmp = projthemes_df[['code', 'name']]
tmp.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Is this reasonable? Is there something simple/better?

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame(projthemes_df[['code', 'name']])
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: I use `copy`: `tmp = projthemes_df[['code', 'name']].copy()`

Answer (score 3):

Use the .copy() method. 
It will create a copy the data instead of giving you a slice of the original dataframe.

```
   tmp = projthemes_df[['code', 'name']].copy()
```

Comment: Technically, it looks like (I hope) this will make a copy of a slice.

Comment: You are correct. In this example the copy is of the slice itself.